Connect to a SharePoint List from tenant A in tenant B with Power Automate

I use a Sharepoint list that exists in tenant A of the organization. This flow runs in tenant B of the organization. When I try to connect to a list from tenant A in tenant B, I get this error:
Could not retrieve values. The dynamic invocation request failed with error: {
  "error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
}.

Who can help me?

You organization architect team can only help you.

Can you explain more, which settings need to be set correctly?

Since both are in different organisation you need to ask them to enable global settings or make organization as expections. If you narate your scenario to Organization Architect he will understand your situation.
